# mysql join not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have 3 tables in mysql database

```
chat
user1, user2, chat_key

chat_seen
msgid, userid, viewed

users
username, status, key
```

So im trying to display the chats ordering them by the users online then messages seen. But its not working. this is what i have so far, iv only got it to work with chat and users, i dont know how to add order by chat seen

```
("SELECT u.random, u.status, c.chat_key, c.seen, u.username
                                     FROM chat c, users u
                                     WHERE CASE 
                                     WHEN c.user1 = ?
                                     THEN c.user2 = u.random
                                     WHEN c.user2 = ?
                                     THEN c.user1= u.random
                                     END 
                                     AND (
                                     c.user1 = ?
                                     OR c.user2 = ?)
                                     ORDER BY u.status DESC LIMIT 50");
```

So the results should be

```
username - online - (2 messages)
username - online - (1 message)

username - offline - (20 messages)
username - offline - (2 messages)
username - offline - (o messages)
```

At the moment i have

```
username - online - (0 messages)
username - online - (0 messages)
username - offline - (2messages)
username - offline - 20 messages)
```

Comment: can you create an SQL fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/), so we can see the data

Comment: Write standard `JOIN` syntax instead of outdated syntax that been gone for over 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query below:

```
("SELECT 
u.random, 
u.status, 
c.chat_key, 
c.seen, 
u.username

FROM chat c, users u

WHERE 
(c.user1 = ? AND c.user2 = u.random)
OR
 (c.user2 = ? AND c.user1 = u.random)
AND 
(c.user1 = ? OR c.user2 = ?)

ORDER BY u.status DESC LIMIT 50");
```

Let me know if it works. :D

Comment: hey, yeah but im trying to order it by chat_seen viewed

Comment: In that case, you can simply change the last line to:

  ORDER BY c.status, c.seen DESC LIMIT 50")

Comment: iv tried but it shows blank. I need it to say select * from chat seen where r.msgid = c.chat_key and r.userid = ? ORDER BY u.status, r.viewed

Comment: I get what you are saying, give me a second. We were having some misunderstanding. :D

Comment: is viewed variable in chat_seen as total number of message the user has seen?

Comment: its just an enun . I think iv set up my structure wrong. Would it be better to add the viewed enun in chat

Comment: so basically my structure is user -> chat -> chat_reply

Comment: I don't think you need to use chat table for the result you want because you only need 3 variables: username, status, and total viewed messages right? Also, do you want still to pass parameters into your where statement like your previous query?